# Installing Xdebug, phpize not table to find package

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

When I try to install **phpize** for my Pop OS VM I get this error. I have done an `sudo apt-get update` as well but am still unable to do it.

I was following the steps that was in this recommendation for Xdebug:

[image: xdebug instructions]

but ...

```
cs@pop-os:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install php-dev.openSUSE
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-dev.openSUSE
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php-dev.openSUSE'
```

Comment: Where does the trailing `.openSUSE` come from? `php-dev` exists, isn't that the one you want?

Comment: You say you're following those instructions, but the command you ran doesn't appear anywhere in them. If you're trying to adapt the instructions for some reason, you'll need to be clearer; otherwise, try running the commands exactly as shown.